# Service class for Archiving and Mirroring Files and Directories

Tags: c#, winforms, file-system

I am writing an application that either mirrors a file/directory into another location or creates a zip file "snap shot" of a file or directory and stores it in another location.  The user is able to create "rules" where they define the source file/directory, the destination file/directory and if they are archiving how many archives to keep.  The user is also able to exclude files/directories if they so choose.  Now this service class is a lot of code and I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.  Of course all of the methods that can be called by the interface are called with a BackgroundWorker.RunAsync() method. Any feed back on how to make this more efficient would be super appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Backupr.Helpers;
using Backupr.Models;

namespace Backupr.Services
{
    public interface IFileActionService
    {
        void ArchiveRule(BackupRule rule);
        void EndOfDay();
    }

    public class FileActionService : IFileActionService
    {     
        public void ArchiveRule(BackupRule rule)
        {
            ArchiveAction archiver = new ArchiveAction(rule);
            archiver.MoveFilesToTemp();
            if (rule.Type == RuleType.Archive)
            {
                archiver.ZipTempFile();
                archiver.MoveArchiveToDestinations();
            }
            else if (rule.Type == RuleType.Mirror)
            {
                archiver.MirrorRule();
            }
            archiver.CleanTempDirectory();
            archiver.CleanOldBackups();
        }

        public void EndOfDay()
        {
            IRuleService ruleService = new RuleService();
            MessageBox.Show("Warning this action will reboot your PC!");
            foreach (BackupRule rule in ruleService.GetAll().Where(r => r.EndOfDay == true))
            {
                ArchiveRule(rule);
            }
            Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "/r /f /t 1");
        }
    }

    // HACK: need to find a better way to handle deleted files and directories.
    // perhaps a logging system that lets the user know the file is missing
    // or just removing the deleted file from the rule.
    // refer to MoveFilesToTemp(), MirrorRule(), DirectoryCopy()
    internal class ArchiveAction
    {
        // TODO: allow users to define archiveName via built in tokens.
        private string archiveName = System.Environment.MachineName + '_' + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
        private BackupRule rule;
        private List<string> excludes = new List<string>();

        public ArchiveAction(BackupRule _rule)
        {
            rule = _rule;
            foreach (BackupPath excludePath in rule.Paths.Where(p => p.Type == PathType.Exclude))
            {
                excludes.Add(excludePath.Value);
            }
        }

        public void MoveFilesToTemp()
        {         
            foreach (BackupPath sourcePath in rule.Paths.Where(p => p.Type == PathType.Source))
            {
                // See comment at top of ArchiveAction Class
                if (PathIsDirectory(sourcePath.Value))
                {
                    DirectoryCopy(sourcePath.Value, Path.Combine(tempDirectory, Path.GetFileName(sourcePath.Value)), true);
                }
                else if (File.Exists(sourcePath.Value) && !excludes.Any(p => p == sourcePath.Value))
                {
                    File.Copy(sourcePath.Value, Path.Combine(tempDirectory, Path.GetFileName(sourcePath.Value)));
                }
            }
        }

        public void ZipTempFile()
        {
            using (Package zip = Package.Open(Path.Combine(Asset.BackuprTempDirectory, archiveName + ".zip"), FileMode.Create))
            {
                foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(tempDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    string packageFile = file.Replace(' ', '_');
                    Uri uri = new Uri(packageFile.Substring(tempDirectory.Length), UriKind.Relative);
                    PackagePart ZipPart = zip.CreatePart(PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(uri), MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip, CompressionOption.Maximum);
                    byte[] B = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
                    ZipPart.GetStream().Write(B, 0, B.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        public void MoveArchiveToDestinations()
        {
            foreach (BackupPath destinationPath in rule.Paths.Where(p => p.Type == PathType.Destination))
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(destinationPath.Value))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath.Value);
                }
                File.Copy(Path.Combine(Asset.BackuprTempDirectory, archiveName + ".zip"), Path.Combine(destinationPath.Value, archiveName + ".zip"));
            }
        }

        public void MirrorRule()
        {
            foreach (BackupPath destinationPath in rule.Paths.Where(p => p.Type == PathType.Destination))
            {
                DirectoryCopy(tempDirectory, destinationPath.Value, true);
            }
        }

        public void CleanTempDirectory()
        {
            Directory.Delete(Asset.BackuprTempDirectory, true);
        }

        public void CleanOldBackups()
        {
            if (rule.Type == RuleType.Archive)
            {
                foreach (BackupPath destinationPath in rule.Paths.Where(p => p.Type == PathType.Destination))
                {
                    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(destinationPath.Value);
                    if (!directory.Exists)
                    {
                        // See comment at top of ArchiveAction Class
                        break;
                    }
                    FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
                    foreach (FileInfo file in files.OrderByDescending(p => p.LastWriteTime).Skip(rule.BackupsToKeep))
                    {
                        string filePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath.Value, file.Name);
                        File.Delete(filePath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private bool PathIsDirectory(string path)
        {
            FileAttributes fileAttribute = File.GetAttributes(@path);
            if ((fileAttribute & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private string tempDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                string directory = Path.Combine(Asset.BackuprTempDirectory, archiveName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
                }
                return directory;
            }
        }

        private void DirectoryCopy(string source, string destination, bool copySubDirectories)
        {
            if (excludes.Any(p => p == source))
            {
                return;
            }

            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(source);
            if (!directory.Exists)
            {
                // See comment at top of ArchiveAction Class
                return;
            }
            if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);
            }
            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                if (!excludes.Any(p => p == file.FullName))
                {
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(destination, file.Name);
                    file.CopyTo(temppath, true);
                }
            }
            if (copySubDirectories)
            {
                DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories();
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectory in subDirectories)
                {
                    if (!excludes.Any(p => p == subDirectory.FullName))
                    {
                        string temppath = Path.Combine(destination, subDirectory.Name);
                        DirectoryCopy(subDirectory.FullName, temppath, copySubDirectories);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **SIDE NOTE:** Everthing is moved to a temp directory first because I was having trouble with the zip method and the DirectoryCopy method not copying a directory directly in the source path root.
>
> *Example:* assuming "C:\Test" is the source and "D:\Backup" is the destination and "C:\Test\directory" has a file in it called "test.txt" the output would look like "D:\Backup\test.txt" instead of "D:\Backup\directory\test.txt", however any directories inside of "C:\Test\directory" would be copied over correctly.

Comment: I failed to mention I am using `System.IO.Packaging` instead of `System.IO.Compression` because this is being developed on .NET 4.0 instead of .NET 4.5

Comment: are you still up to solve this problem? there are lots of problem , but I need to see some more code as present code did not compile

Comment: That's all of it

Comment: I could not find Backupr.Helpers and Backupr.Models; in code

Comment: Those are the name spaces that contain my entity classes and the `Asset` class which defines `backuprTempDirectory`. The name of the app is backupr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rule has been passed to ArchiveAction class , you dont need to check type inside ArchiveRule class. Move all processing related code to the process method like ZipTempFile ,MoveArchiveToDestinations

```
 
        //inside FileActionService 
        public void ArchiveRule(BackupRule rule)
        {
            ArchiveAction archiver = new ArchiveAction(rule);
            archiver.Process();
        }

       //inside ArchiveAction class 
       public void Process()
        {
            if (rule.Type == RuleType.Archive)
            {
                ZipTempFile();
                MoveArchiveToDestinations();
            }
            else if (rule.Type == RuleType.Mirror)
            {
                MirrorRule();
            }

            CleanTempDirectory();
            CleanOldBackups();
        }
```

once this is done you can further refactor your if else clause in a strategy pattern , 
so you will need a factory which will return class will handle the Archive rule or mirror rule inside a different class and your FileActionService  will contain only processing logic

Comment: What is the difference of having the Process() method and just doing that in the ArchiveRule() method? I see no real advantage to moving the logic?

Comment: by doing so you dont have to clutter ur code in FileActionService  , so can be used by any other code which need this kind of thing

Comment: valid... I didn't think of that.